# Delegate methods not calling in UITextField custom subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am creating a custom subclass from UITextField class. I want to apply something while textfield is focused. But in my custom class my delegate methods are not calling.

I have create a subclass that extends UITextField class and make some customisation.

In TGTextField class:

```
class TGTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    delegate = self
    createBorder()
}
required override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    delegate = self
    createBorder()
}
func createBorder(){
    self.layer.borderColor = AppColor.TextFieldColors.BorderNormalColor.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("focused")
    self.activeTextFieldColor()
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("lost focus")
     self.deactiveTextFieldColor()
}

func activeTextFieldColor(){
    self.layer.borderColor = AppColor.TextFieldColors.BorderActiveColor.cgColor
}
func deactiveTextFieldColor(){
    self.layer.borderColor = AppColor.TextFieldColors.BorderNormalColor.cgColor
}
}
```

Both these delegates methods are not called.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("focused")
    self.activeTextFieldColor()
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    print("lost focus")
     self.deactiveTextFieldColor()
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't implement the delegate methods here. Implement it where you are using TGTextField.

Comment: But There is a general behaviour that need to implement on all TGTextFields.

Comment: Then you can add methods and call them from wherever you implement the delegate.

Comment: I think that will not solve the problem. Can you explain a little with example please ?

Comment: @MuhammadWasim Does init code is called??

Comment: Which version of swift are you using?

Comment: @dahiya_boy Yes, it is being called and i can see the border that is created in init method.

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio I am using Swift 5.

Comment: @MuhammadWasim Can you put the break point and confirm? In both init methods

Comment: @dahiya_boy Yes break point stopped 3 times as i am having 3 TGTextField in first screen.

Comment: @MuhammadWasim Rico is right .. check his answer. Its also can be a root cause of issue.

Comment: His answer really make sense but that was also warning from Xcode and added _ but it is not the root of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works for me. These delegate methods in the custom class won't be called if you set text field delegate to the corresponding view controller after you've initialized the text fields.

To avoid this add target in `TGTextField` instead of `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
class TGTextField: UITextField {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        //delegate = self
        createBorder()
    }
    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //delegate = self
        createBorder()
    }
    func createBorder(){
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(activeTextFieldColor), for: .editingDidBegin)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(deactiveTextFieldColor), for: .editingDidEnd)
    }
    @objc func activeTextFieldColor(){
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    }
    @objc func deactiveTextFieldColor(){
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one, but still doesn't make sense that delegate is not working 

Comment: Awesome Answer :)

Comment: Wowww ! Its superb awesome. It worked ! Have great evening.

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio For ex. If you have `var nameTextField = TGTextField()` in `LoginVC`. And in `LoginVC`'s 'viewDidLoad` if you set  `nameTextField.delegate = self`, then delegate methods from the custom class won't be called

Comment: @RajeshKumarR ah, right I didn't get what you mean, of course it will not work. This is the best approach btw

Comment: It really make sense! Appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're implementing the wrong method signature; you should put `_` before `textField`, like this

```swift
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {}
```

---

Xcode should help you highlighting with a warning

> Instance method 'textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' of protocol 'UITextFieldDelegate'

Comment: Ohh Nice catch 

Comment: @Rico Crescenzio Thanks a lot for looking at it with me. I did it and Still its same issue.

Comment: Mh, I tried in playground and it's working; try to `CMD + SHIFT + K` and run it again

Comment: Sadly, I have gone through code several time cleans project, Restart Xcode but still its basic implementation and its not working.

Comment: That's crazy, there must be something else

Comment: Are you using interface builder or manually adding the subview? If you're using the interface builder, are you sure you set up the custom class correctly?